# Simplify regular expression decimal with dot

Tags: regex

In C++, I need to create pattern which match decimal values consist of at least one digit either before or after the decimal point. However, the decimal point is also optional.

Examples which should match:

```
10  
1 
.123
123.
12.123
```

at the moment I have something like this, but need something simpler.

```
(\d+\.?)|(\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d+)
```

Comment: Remember that the `.` character is a special character in regular expressions. You need to escape it.

Comment: did you use the search function on this site or google?

Comment: i use "\" before . but stack overflow editor deleted it. edited

Comment: You can use: `^(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$`

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you can use this regex:

```
^(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzZAMo/5)

- `\d+\.?\d*` will match a digit without decimal point or something like `123.` or a number with decimal point.
- `\.\d+` will match a number starting with decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I can simplify it with the info you've provided.

```
(\d+\.?\d*)|(\d*\.?\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d*\.?\d*
```

I am not sure if this works in C++ but it does work in Javascript/Python with your examples.

Note: This will include `.`

Comment: This will also match with just `.`

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was allowed - will make an edit to the answer.

Comment: I deleted my suggestion, because that still matches a single `.`